# Webappclass loader unable to load superclass in a hook?

Tags: hook, liferay, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

I am using liferay ce 6.1.0.I need to extend LayoutAction class in a hook.But the class cannot be loaded in the hook by the class loader

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/action/LayoutAction
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
```

Is this the issue with the class loader or am I supposed use a different subclass of the following in order to extends.
Thanks in advance

I want to override includeLayoutContent() method of LayoutAction class in order to have a track on the number of views of a page.If this class cannot be extended,is there any other means or class which can be extended to achieve the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction` is in portal-impl.jar, which is not available to hooks. Therefor you cannot do this.

<strike>If you would give us a hint what you want to achieve with this, somebody might be able to tell you how to do what you want to do.</strike>

With your added information I'll give you a hint: Typically, a write operation for every pageview is considered to be quite expensive: Your portal's performance will suffer from this. I'd rather advise to use external tools like google anayltics, piwik or similar ones to generate statistics, including the pageviews for specific pages.

Another method, if you can live with the lower potential performance, is to embed such a method in your theme - the theme gets access to the current page and can execute additional functionality with this. Preferably you'll position this at the end of the page, when everything else has already been rendered and sent to the client.

Comment: Thanks Olaf..Updating the question for the same

Comment: Thanks Olaf,the theme solution seems feasible enough to me.